# symfony2 phpunit - functional testing error (host_with_path)

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, functional-testing, symfony-2.6

So thanks to Matteo ([phpunit in symfony2 - No tests executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29409761/phpunit-in-symfony2-no-tests-executed)) I can now test my functional tests.

Now I got the following error when running `phpunit -c app`:

```
 You must change the main Request object in the front controller (app.php)
 in order to use the `host_with_path` strategy.
```

so I did change it in the app.php, from:

```
$request = RequestFactory::createFromGlobals('host_with_path');
```

to:

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
```

I also updated my swiftmailer-bundle from version 2.3 to 5.4.0.
Unfortunately This did not fix my error.

and this is my ***../app/config_test.yml***

```
swiftmailer:
disable_delivery: true
```

Am I missing something here?

I cannot seem to find this error anywhere on the web. Does someone know how I should fix this error?

After some searching I noticed that the app.php wasn't the problem. It was the DefaultControllerTest.php. The error could be fixed by removing the following lines from the DefaultControllerTest:

```
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/hello/Fabien');

    $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('html:contains("Hello Fabien")')->count() > 0);
```

**Due to recent developments our development team decided to stop using Sonata. As a side effect this bug got fixed. So I won't have a solution for this problem.**

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, that the Client object is using neither app.php nor app_dev.php.

The client creates the request internally. So it won't be the request you need.

The only solution I can see is to override the method `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase::createClient` to return your own client. This client is than responsible for creating the actual request object. The following is the current behavior.

```
namespace Symfony\Component\HttpKernel;

use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client as BaseClient;

class Client extends BaseClient
{
  ...
  /**
     * Converts the BrowserKit request to a HttpKernel request.
     *
     * @param DomRequest $request A DomRequest instance
     *
     * @return Request A Request instance
     */
    protected function filterRequest(DomRequest $request)
    {
        $httpRequest = Request::create($request->getUri(), $request->getMethod(), $request->getParameters(), $request->getCookies(), $request->getFiles(), $request->getServer(), $request->getContent());
        foreach ($this->filterFiles($httpRequest->files->all()) as $key => $value) {
            $httpRequest->files->set($key, $value);
        }
        return $httpRequest;
    }
  ...
}
```

You have to override method `filterRequest` to return kind of a request you want.